# Operand expected: syntax error (comparing statement)

Tags: shell-script

getting this error while comparing wget results:

```
mpa=$(wget http://xxxxxxxx/api/pages/ZZZZ-YYYY -q -O -)
  echo $mpa
if (($mpa = "{"'"'name'"'":"'"'ZZZZ-YYYY'"','"'active'"':true}"" )); then
    echo "CRITICAL: Up."
else
    echo "OK: Down."
fi
```

---

the error that comes:

```
./mpa: line 25: ((: {"name":"ZZZZ-YYYY","active":true} = {"name":"ZZZZ-YYYY","active":true} : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "{"name":"ZZZZ-YYYY","active":true} = {"name":"ZZZZ-YYYY","active":true} ")
OK: Down
```

not sure where is the error;

when i try to echo:

```
mpa="{"'"'name'"'":"'"'ZZZZ-YYYY'"','"'active'"':true}""
```

the result is fine:

```
echo $mpa
{"name":"ZZZZ-YYYY","active":true}
```

but when comparing it in if statement it is showing this error.

Answer (score 1):

Your `if` statement is a syntax error.  The correct way to perform a string comparison would be:

```
if [[ "testcase" == "$variable" ]]; then
    do_stuff
else
    do_other_stuff
fi
```